# why does Wordpress custom css convert alpha to hex values?

Tags: css

When I use the custom css functionality in wordpress jetpack I find that sometimes when saving that it will render my rgba values as css...WHY?!?!?!

`text-shadow: 0 0 0 #cac5c5 1px 1px 0 #484646 2px 2px 0 #1f1e1e 3px 3px 0 #10da4e;
}`

Well the original code is:

`text-shadow: 0 0 0 rgb(202,197,197), 1px 1px 0 rgb(72,70,70), 2px 2px 0 rgb(31,30,30), 3px 3px 0 rgb(16,218,78);`

Not sure what causes this so I was hoping someone else here has experienced this and how they worked around it - I was thinking I could just mess with the raw `style.css` of my child template

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not mistaken, not all browsers are 100% compatible with RGB color codes, so it might be happening in an effort to maximize cross-browser uniformity of appearance.

this could also be done to facilitate transparency effects, which might be in another option field for Jetpack. there's definitely less browser support for the extended hex use for alpha transparency, VS rgb transparency.

since extra commas and "px" characters are being stripped out as well, it could be happening in an effort to reduce code size. there may be an option for "optimizing files" somewhere you have enabled.

i'm sorry i can not suggest a work-around, i don't use Jetpack.

Comment: please answers are supposed to be more than guesses

Comment: no answer of any kind had been suggested in the 90 days since the OP asked the question, and you complain about my answer less than 24 hours after i posted it. how is your scolding my answer any more helpful to OP than my "guesses" as you describe them? my "guesses" are at least potentially assistive in offering a direction to do more research, since the OP might have been unfamiliar with browser compatibility issues with hex VS RGB or some plugins optimizing code when you save it.

Comment: if you have problems with how the site works please go to the meta section and raise them. This kind of grumpy old men comments got tired years ago